Highly oscillatory cubic spline interpolation for apparently smooth data
I tried all the different interpolation kinds of interp1d of scipy.
It seems linear and slinear are the best, but they are obviously rough linear approximations and I need something smooth. I tried cubic and quadratic, but they give too many oscillations.
In the following images, I create 3 datasets of values from the points plotted. Each dataset has values so close to the points plotted you can't actually distinguish them.
Each dataset has its own interpolation, so there are 3 different interpolations with the same kind of function. This way I'm able to interpolate these points with little variations.
Cubic interpolation:

Linear interpolation:

I still need to try makima, akima, and other stuff, but I don't know if they will help, given how the cubic behaves.

Edit: The issue was that having some repetitive measures in the x data meant that there were clusters around some values which caused the interpolation to go crazy. I removed the extra points and the cubic now interpolates as expected.
Based on the comments, I would be interested in seeing how I might fit a function to this data.
x_axis = np.array([0.19092153, 0.22054906, 0.20479037, 0.2405085,  0.26400153, 0.29241053,
 0.32941269, 0.37356609, 0.42920922, 0.57699022, 0.75048209, 0.49836091,
 0.91334163, 0.83498366, 1.17289487, 1.22645544, 0.66256894, 1.27589559,
 0.98658466, 1.05254969, 1.114606,   0.40041087, 0.46282709,
 0.53626834, 0.61943812, 0.706282,   0.87466503, 0.79338356, 0.94967975,
 1.02055141, 1.08372781])

x_axis_err = np.array([0.00027437, 0.00028862, 0.0002815,  0.00030131, 0.00031731, 0.00033934,
 0.00036759, 0.00039672, 0.00042875, 0.00049559, 0.00052638, 0.00046681,
 0.00054481, 0.00053538, 0.00060653, 0.00062872, 0.00051641, 0.00065084,
 0.00055359, 0.00056984, 0.00058847, 0.00041391, 0.00044934,
 0.00048197, 0.00050741, 0.00052475, 0.00054113, 0.0005305,  0.00054822,
 0.00056075, 0.00057903])

y_axis=np.array([1.9041,   1.854611, 1.881278, 1.815482, 1.770929, 1.715659, 1.642026, 1.54932,
 1.450081, 1.251631, 1.119345, 1.346291, 1.060515, 1.084082, 1.022619, 1.018929,
 1.175287, 1.016079, 1.044855, 1.034899, 1.027848, 1.501344, 1.397873,
 1.297187, 1.209863, 1.144972, 1.070685, 1.099807, 1.051746, 1.039288, 1.031   ])

y_axis_err = np.array([1.983e-03, 1.855e-03, 1.933e-03, 1.752e-03, 1.656e-03, 1.535e-03, 1.414e-03,
 1.225e-03, 1.046e-03, 6.630e-04, 3.330e-04, 8.590e-04, 1.590e-04, 2.310e-04,
 4.600e-05, 3.700e-05, 4.840e-04, 3.100e-05, 1.090e-04, 8.000e-05, 6.000e-05,
 1.142e-03, 9.520e-04, 7.610e-04, 5.660e-04, 4.040e-04, 1.890e-04,
 2.790e-04, 1.300e-04, 9.200e-05, 6.800e-05])


[ask] and [mre]

I appreciate your help, but I can't send the data required

You need to put up the table of numbers for x and y if anyone is going to help you. It looks to me like a low order rational approximation would ace that function. Not by interpolating it as such - but computing a model that fits the observations instead. The data look clean enough to fit an empirical function to it or possibly an actual theoretical function with a few parameters if you told us what that data represents.

Ok, so, solved. The issue was that having some repetitive measures in the x_axis, when creating random values around them, some values were very near one to each other. So much that cubic went crazy. I removed them and cubic now interpolate right.

@MartinBrown I updated the question with the dataset. Even though now there is no issue with cubic spline interpolation, I'm curios on how you would fit this, as it's something I wish to try but didn't success to (gaussian doesn't work)

You havent posted your code. Which is the most relevant part needed on the question.

There is no need for the code, as the interpolation poses no issues now. I was more interested in the answer of @MartinBrown

As suggested in the comments, you can fit the data using a simple rational function. I went with a 2nd-order polynomial numerator and the same for the denominator. This produces a very good fit (RMSE = 1.72e-12).
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

plt.close("all")

x = np.array([0.19092153, 0.22054906, 0.20479037, 0.2405085,  0.26400153,
              0.29241053, 0.32941269, 0.37356609, 0.42920922, 0.57699022,
              0.75048209, 0.49836091, 0.91334163, 0.83498366, 1.17289487,
              1.22645544, 0.66256894, 1.27589559, 0.98658466, 1.05254969,
              1.114606,   0.40041087, 0.46282709, 0.53626834, 0.61943812,
              0.706282,   0.87466503, 0.79338356, 0.94967975, 1.02055141,
              1.08372781])
y = np.array([1.9041,   1.854611, 1.881278, 1.815482, 1.770929, 1.715659, 
              1.642026, 1.54932, 1.450081, 1.251631, 1.119345, 1.346291, 
              1.060515, 1.084082, 1.022619, 1.018929, 1.175287, 1.016079, 
              1.044855, 1.034899, 1.027848, 1.501344, 1.397873, 1.297187, 
              1.209863, 1.144972, 1.070685, 1.099807, 1.051746, 1.039288, 
              1.031])

sort_ind = np.argsort(x)
x = x[sort_ind]
y = y[sort_ind]


def fit_func(x, a, b, c, d, e):
    return (a*x**2 + b*x + c)/(d*x**2 + e*x + 1.)


popt, _ = curve_fit(fit_func, x, y)

print({key:val for key, val in zip("abcde", popt)})

y_fit = fit_func(x, *popt)
RMSE = np.sqrt(np.sum(y - y_fit)**2/y.size)
print(f"RMSE = {RMSE:.3e}")

x_fine = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
y_fine = fit_func(x_fine, *popt)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, ".", label="data")
ax.plot(x_fine, y_fine, label="fit")
ax.legend()

fig.show()

Coefficients:
a: 5.165889390950292, 
b: -2.8393795779447597, 
c: 2.039612297891438, 
d: 4.683313324059559, 
e: -1.4953523785898504

Fit plot:

